# fnctl : invalid argument in C

Tags: c, file-locking, inter-process-communicat

I m working with File Locking in interprocess Communication , 
the following code bugs me...
when run through terminal in Macintosh

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <errno.h>
    #include <fcntl.h>
    #include <unistd.h>

  int main(int argc , char *argv[])
  {
   // l_type , l_whence , l_start , l_len , l_pid
    struct flock f1 = {F_WRLCK , SEEK_SET , 0 , 0 , 0};
    int fd;

  f1.l_pid = getpid() ;

// if command line arguments  , then assign a Read Lock
if (argc > 1)
{
    f1.l_type = F_RDLCK ;
}

if ((fd = open("lockdemo.c", O_RDWR)) == -1)
{
    perror("open");
    exit(1);
}

printf("Press <RETURN> to try to get lock");
getchar() ;

printf("trying to get lock...");

if (fcntl(fd, F_SETLKW , &f1)  == -1)
{
    perror("fcntl");
    exit(1);
}


printf("got lock !\n");
printf("Press <RETURN> to release lock:");
getchar();

f1.l_type = F_UNLCK ; //set to unlock same region

if (fcntl(fd, F_SETLK , &f1) == -1)
{
    perror("fcntl");
    exit(1);
}

printf("Unlocked .. \n");
close(fd);

return 0;
 }
```

But the following error appears :
fnctl : invalid argument

plz help me in this question...

Comment: _Which_ `fcntl` call is it that gives the error?

Comment: the one after the "trying to get the block"

Comment: Sir , u have gud reputation points...will u plz make a Chat room for C Programmers ...there is already a room <Lounge-C> ..but inactive...and <Lounge-C++> does not allow me to ask quetions ...So Sir PLZ .....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On MacOs, the members of `struct flock` have a different order than in Linux.

to make your code portable you should assign the fields by name, and not assume a particular order.

From the MacOS Man page for fcntl:

```
         struct flock {
             off_t       l_start;    /* starting offset */
             off_t       l_len;      /* len = 0 means until end of file */
             pid_t       l_pid;      /* lock owner */
             short       l_type;     /* lock type: read/write, etc. */
             short       l_whence;   /* type of l_start */
         };
```

Comment: That's a very valid point and possibly would be the cause of problem faced by the OP. +1

Comment: YES sir....thank you !!!!! 
It worked ... it correctly shows the file locking and also the waiting  to  get a lock ... :) thank you !!!!

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it works fine without any modification on Linux Min 12 64 bit.

```
 gcc lock.c 
-Compaq-6200-Pro-MT-PC ~/Dropbox/Misc $ ./a.out 1
Press <RETURN> to try to get lock
trying to get lock...got lock !
Press <RETURN> to release lock:
Unlocked .. 
-Compaq-6200-Pro-MT-PC ~/Dropbox/Misc $ ./a.out
Press <RETURN> to try to get lock
trying to get lock...got lock !
Press <RETURN> to release lock:
Unlocked ..
```

Of course i created a lockdemo.c file in the same folder.

Seems like your locking api on mac might have issues.

Comment: according to the program , the file should get WRITE LOCK if no argument is passed...but if no argument is passed , it shows the above error

Comment: do you have write access to the file lockdemo.c? create it yourself locally to make sure

Comment: Check the solution posted by @Klas Lindbäck. That most likely is the cause of your error.

Comment: Take this as a lesson and always fill structure fields by name.